How to solve type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ question: string; answer: string; }[]'?
i've looked into other answers, but still can't solve the issue: using i18n i'm getting typescript mistake "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ question: string; answer: string; }[]'" and "Error: text.map is not a function".
I have translations stored in JSON as an array. Page.tsx file + my Data component that receives props. I'm a beginner with TS and i guess mistake is related to my incorrect choice of types in Data component or to JSON array format. I'd appreciate any help.
Translations in JSON:
 "data": {
    "title": "Title",
    "text": [
{      "question": "questionOne",
      "solution": "solutionOne"},
{  "question": "questionTwo",
      "solution": "solutionTwo"},
}, 
...etc.]

Code in Data component:
export type DataProps = {
  title: string;
  text: { question: string; solution: string }[];
};

export default function Data({ title, text }: DataProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Title>{title}</Title>
      <div className={styles.block_questions}>
        {text.map(({ question, solution}, i) => {
      ...

page.tsx:
type Props = {
  params: {
    locale: string;
  };
};

export default async function App({ params: { locale } }: Props) {
  unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);
  const t = await getTranslations('');

 return (
    <main>
      <Data title={t('data.title')} text={t('data.text', { returnObjects: true })}></Data>
    </main>
  );
}

mistake "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ question: string; solution: string; }[]" appears in page.tsx - above the "text" attribute of Data.
Tried to change format of JSON translations, type of props in Data.

The t function accepts a generic parameter type that can be set to define what type is returned, like this: t<{ question: string; solution: string }[]>('data.text', { returnObjects: true }) It will tell to the TypeScript compiler the correct type instead of string.

Hi, Xartok, thanks for answer. Do you mean adding line to page.tsx, as follows?
...
<Data
title={t('data.title')}
text={t<{ question: string; solution: string }[]>('data.text', { returnObjects: true })}
>

If i do so, i still get "text.map is not a function" error and in page.tsx error remains too ("Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ question: string; answer: string; }[]")

Ok, can you do a console.log of t('data.text', { returnObjects: true }) inside the App function under const t = await getTranslations(''); ? Also, what does getTranslations returns exactly ?
